# Gemini Pro API's response ommits the "text" field when I ask to translate a document

Tags: llm, api

I integrate Gemini Pro into one of our internal tools to allow users to "ask" the documents in our database.

It all worked fine until I was conducting some tests today and noticed that the response objects simply omits the `text` field when I ask it to translate the document (originally in french) to english.

This came as a surprise to me, and searching in the API documentation, there's no mention of this procedure. Is this a bug or a feature and are there any sources to read more about this and how to mitigate against it?

Comment: Would you mind sharing two sample responses, one with `text` and one without?

Comment: Have you checked the `finishReason` property for documents that comeback with empty results? Also, you should check the `blocked` flag and if it's `true`, check the `errors` field.